# Filter by Point in Polygon and Return County ID/Name

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have redone this approach, but still have not got it working. This time I have a working example that is very short and illustrates the problem perfectly:

https://bl.ocks.org/diggetybo/raw/6d35e5ecd17992650d0a23896e649b25/

In the above block you will see a map of counties. Also, I have user inputs for latitude and longitude like so:

```
var lat = d3.select('#lat_input').node();

var long = d3.select('#long_input').node();
```

These coordinates could be anywhere within the US. What I want to do is create a function that queries the user input coordinates and returns the FIPS id of the county.

```
   var containing_county = us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(polygon) {
       return d3.polygonContains(polygon, [long.value, lat.value]);
   });
   console.log(containing_county)
 });
```

However it is not filtering the way I'd expect it to, it's saying cannot read property 0 of undefined.

What should be done differently here?

also tried:

```
    var containing_county = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features.filter(function(d) { 
return d3.polygonContains(d.geometry, [long.value, lat.value]);
    });
```

Comment: could you please provide a working example?

Comment: finally got around to providing a working example just now.

Comment: you're still passing a MultiPolygon parameter instead of an expected Polygon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the data you linked.
Element 0 of objects.counties.geometries is not of type 'Polygon', but a 'MultiPolygon'.
The first parameter of d3.polygonContains expects a polygon, and cannot handle multipolygons. Probably you should use different methods on different geometries.

Comment: You were the only one who stuck with me on this. So I think you earned it. Although your answer makes sense now, it winded up taking the following to return the object containing the FIPS id: `var containing_county = mapData.filter(function(polygon) {
     if(polygon.geometry !== null) {
       return d3.polygonContains(polygon.geometry.coordinates[0], [long.value, lat.value])` so I had to add in the coordinate feature and then slice it at zero.

Comment: @ArashHowaida, did that solve your problem? Is it working now?

Comment: yea the line of code in the comment above did it for me. The key was slicing at 0 and adding `.coordinates`, neither of which I had done previously.